# Determine checked box status on page load, disable closest input if checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

I have a form which promts users for input, however each field has an 'unavailable' checkbox incase data is not available.

Note the checkboxes are of the form:

```
<input id="un_123" class="unavailable" type="checkbox" name="un_123" value="unavailable">
```

If users select this, I have the following jquery to disable the field

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.unavailable').change(function() {
        var i = $(this).prev('input'),
            d = i.attr('disabled');
            i.attr('disabled', !d);
            i.val('Unavailable');
    });
});
```

Which toggles the field as disabled with the check box.

However when the page loads the state of the checkbox is preserved (if checked this is recorded in a table and referenced on page load to load it as checked or not checked, however the field is obviously loaded as not disabled.

I have multiple instances of these field / checkbox pairings on a page, so I want to be able to check on page load which are loaded checked, and then disable the field closest to each of them.

But without the .change trigger and relying on `this` I'm not sure how to proceed?

I've tried:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
      if($('.unavailable').is(':checked')){
        var i = $('.unavailable').prev('input'),
            d = i.attr('disabled');
            i.attr('disabled', !d);
            i.val('Unavailable');   
     }
});
```

But it didn't work (page loaded with all inputs next to checkboxes disabled)

Comment: Just add `.trigger('change')` to the handler

Comment: Sorry I'm unfamiliar - to which version? My existing jquery that works when the checkbox is changed? How should I add that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/85pr7y3z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input.unavailable').change(function() {
                    var i = $(this).parent().prev('input'),
                            d = i.attr('disabled');
                            i.attr('disabled', !d);
                            i.val('Unavailable');
            });
    $('input.unavailable:checked').each(function(){
        var i = $(this).parent().prev('input');
        i.prop('disabled', true);
        i.val('Unavailable');});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lfjj8LrL/

Comment: I can see how this should work but for some reason it's not working for my page - there's no errors in the console, not sure how to debug it.

Comment: What's your version of jQuery and where do you put it on your page? Can I see the whole page source?

Comment: 1.11.1 (tested it as fine on your js fiddle and it was). tried putting it at bottom of body initially and then in head, but both times wrapped in a 'on DOM ready wrapper' so I figure that shouldn't matter.

Fro entire source - sure - it's in development so there's some messy test arrays in the source, but currently the jquery you recommended sits at line 522 here:http://pastebin.com/cqAbXvQJ

Comment: Gideon, you put it into wrong place. Just put the code inside `document.ready` after your `change`. External `$()` is synonym of `document.ready`. Please remove it if you put it into yours (see the updated listing and the fiddle).

Comment: Thanks for your notes - I've copy pasted just as you have it, and it's still not disabling the checked inputs on page load. I added in an alert inside the each(function() and am getting the corresponging number of alerts to checked boxes on a page - so all should be working, but it's just not disabling them in the way it does when I check them :( Updated pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/xZ1Ef6NU

relevent code now at line 64

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74382/discussion-between-oleg-k-and-gideon).

Comment: I think it's missing a  set of ` });` (I initially pasted in latest edit and got console complaints). I added it and got the same result as before: checkbox toggle applied state fine, but on page load, nothing.